# Django model validate two ArrayFields have the same length

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

Given two `ArrayField's`, how you can validate the length of both are always the same?

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField

class MyModel(models.Model):
    x = ArrayField(models.FloatField())
    y = ArrayField(models.FloatField())
```

I know you can specific the `ArrayField` size parameter to be the same on both, but what if I want the size to be variable for each record?

Comment: I'm little bit confused what you mean by validating that they are the same length, while at the same time saying that you want the size to not be fixed. 

Do you mean that for instance A both arrays are for example 3 items long, while in instance B both arrays are for example 5 items long?

Comment: No for both of them to be 3 or 5, just not both fixed to a constant 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do custom validation with Django models by overriding the `Model.clean()` method ([Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean)).

> This method should be used to provide custom model validation, and to modify attributes on your model if desired.

So you should be able to write something like this:

```py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    x = ArrayField(models.FloatField())
    y = ArrayField(models.FloatField())

    def clean(self):
        if len(self.x) != len(self.y):
            raise ValidationError("The arrays do not have the same length.")
```

`Model.clean()` is executed as part of the `Model.full_clean()` validation flow. Notice that it's not executed on `Model.save()`. If you would like to execute it and validate that they are the same length on the `Model.save()` method, you will have to override `Model.save()` and call `Model.full_clean()` in it.